Spring Security - JWT Decoder - does it get called every request
I have a question about the JwT decoder in Spring Security.
My implementation looks like this
@Configuration
internal class JwtConfig(
    private val serverProperties: ServerProperties,
) {

    @Bean
    // for decoding JWT tokens
    fun jwtDecoder() : ReactiveJwtDecoder {
        return NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder
            .withJwkSetUri(serverProperties.auth0JwKeySetUri)
            .build()
    }
}

the jwkseturi is an external endpoint with the public jwt key to verify signing.
The auth manager then uses it here:
 val jwtAuthManager = JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager(jwtDecoder)
        jwtAuthManager.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtTokenConverter)

This then gets plugged into the main Spring security chain.
My question is does this endpoint get called for EVERY request? If so, isn't this resource intensive, just as token introspection is for opaque tokens....?

It should be called for any request that requires authorization.  The main use of this kind of token is to get away from using server-side session vars (can be resource hogs with lots of traffic), or making DB calls.  It's worth benchmarking to see if DB call is more or less resource intensive than validating signature of token.  I wouldn't bother with benchmarking against server-side session vars as it's pretty well-known that with lots of traffic they're pretty evil.  (the problem is when to get rid of them...)

Since the key is relatively static, unless I manually rotate it (eg. in Auth 0), is there anyway of caching it locally, and maybe doing a call every 1 hour?

I believe this only gets the key sets (public keys) at startup.  I think I misunderstood your question.  The intensive part is validating the signature...  since that's a config I'd expect the key set would already be in memory, though I don't know what it does if the authorization server rotates it's keys.  (it may re-get the config property via endpoint?  the key set should then have old and new keys methinks)

I'm not expert on this, btw... you're likely to get a much better answer on Security Exchange:  https://security.stackexchange.com/
